# Update the sqlite database by making web service calls at regular intervals in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, timer, synchronization

I have a Java JsonRPC webservice application(we can also think of it as a client application that uses other web services.) This jsonrpc webservice application has a sqlite db.

This web service is doing a number of tasks (such as calling web services, sending transactions, querying balance, etc.).
These calls are transactions made by the user.

Another important task of this web service is to update the local database (sqlite) by making a web service call at regular intervals (10 seconds).

The process that runs continuously with this 10 second time interval should not interfere with other read and write operations.

How can I find a solution for this problem? Should I create a child thread in the java main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , creating another Thread will work bu another cleaner approach is to use Spring Quartz